# What is difference between current and voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, batteries

If current passes through the bulb not using it up then how battery becomes weak after sometime?

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsSE! The title of your question does not match the body of your question. Could you please fix this, as well as give more detail in your question body? I am currently (pun always intended) confused as to what you really want to know here.

Comment: Are you asking about the workings of a battery or about the general concepts of currents and voltages in electronics?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is found in multiple elementary textbooks.

Comment: See this answer, possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323595/

Comment: Please re-open. It is obvious to me what they are asking (essentially, why do batteries stop working if they don't lose or gain electrons) and it is not a duplicate of the link provided, which is similar but different.

Comment: Hanzala, think of a fresh battery as two parts, a bladder filled with balls (electrons) and a sponge with lots of holes. When you connect a pipe (wire) from the bladder to the sponge, the balls flow though the pipe. Eventually the bladder will run out of balls or the sponge will fill with them, and then your battery is dead. The light bulb actually slows this process down, essentially by squeezing the pipe partially shut. If you just connect a wire with no lamp, the battery will die very rapidly indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The bulb needs a lot of current to produce light, a little current does not make light but still uses the battery.